# Multiple occurances of the same Column variable in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

1. **TicketsForSale**

   - ticket_id (PK)
   - type
   - category
2. **Transactions**

   - transaction_id (PK)
   - ticket_id (FK)

I want to get the transactions per type of tickets. This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT ticketsforsale.type 
      , COUNT(transactions.ticket_id)
FROM  ticketsforsale  
        INNER JOIN transactions ON ticketsforsale.ticket_id = transactions.ticket_id 
GROUP BY ticketsforsale.type
```

What I hope for as a result is something like this

```
{ 
    Sports  5
    Theater 7
    Cruise 8
    Cinema 10 
}
```

But instead I get the following :

```
{  Theater 2 
   Cruise  1 
   Sports  1 
   Sports  2 
   Cruise  3 
   Cinema 5 
}
```

The numbers aren't accurate, just used for demonstration.

(The category column is listing the specific show you attend by "purchasing" the ticket. E.G If the type is "Sports", the category could be Basketball or Football or Volleyball etc. etc. ) I just thought that this column could somehow be the issue here, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You seem to have different categories that look the same but are different, somehow -- trailing spaces, different characters, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct type
     , encode(type::bytea,'hex') hex_type
  from TicketsForSale order by 1;
```

You'll probably find that you have multiple type values that appear identical but have different hexadecimal representations.  Fix those discrepancies, and the you should be good to go.